# How to detect if a process runs longer than X seconds, then do something with it?

Tags: shell-script, process, cron, ffmpeg, supervisord

I’m on debian.

I am calling a ffmpeg process to generate a mp3. this gets called from a php script using shell_exec. This works fine 99% of the time.

Sometimes, the ffmpeg process doesn’t exit and I’m left with ffmpeg running for hours. I”m slowly tweaking the params and its happening less, but still crops up on occasion.

When I look at the top processes I sometimes find it sitting there eating the cpu and disk, the process hasn’t terminated.

`993 www-data  20   0  252012  38904  27384 R  99.7   1.9 390:09.84 ffmpeg`

I normally look for the process (and confirm it’s the right one by ensuring the params it executed with match my php script:

`ps -eo args | grep ffmpeg`

then get its process id and kill it, and go hunt down the file it was working on and trash that too

`-rw-r--r--   1 www-data www-data  14G Feb  9 21:20  cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da.mp3` - uh oh

I’m not sure what words I should be googling for.

I’m looking for ideas for a supervisory process or script that I can run through a supervisord/cron job that can output all processes that run for longer than X seconds, and pipe their process details into a script that can match the process with arguments matching a pattern (using some kind of nasty regex I imagine), kill the process and go trash any files matching on their arguments.

Comment: You can use cron to run ps for your user, grep for ffmpeg, check the cpu usage and/or elapsed time, and choose to kill it. It would probably be easier to save the list of the files to be deleted per process when it is started. You might try lsof, but that would omit files that have been closed. Basically, automate your existing manual process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [timeout](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/coreutils/timeout.1.en.html) that runs a command with a time limit.

For example:

```
timeout 2 yes
```

Will echo 'y' for two seconds (it would go on forever otherwise).

Comment: My command might also be creating large (temporary or permanent) files inside that process, which I need to find and remove IF the process timed out (otherwise they are valid). How would php `shell_exec` know whether the process exited cleanly or was terminated by `timeout`?

Comment: The [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/coreutils/timeout.1.en.html) states that `timeout` will send a signal (you decide which) to your process, if you catch it, then you can do whatever needs to be done at that time, before you exit. If you cannot modify the program to trap the signal, say for example SIGUSR1, then a wrapper script coud be used to call your program and host the signal catching logic.

Comment: You can also [check `timeout`’s exit code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205080/86440) to determine whether it timed out.